# Php Openssl not loading why?

Tags: php, openssl

I am running a tweaked webmail application. However, for some reason the openssl extension isn't loading. I have enabled it in the php.ini, but when I run my application and check for loaded extensions using get_loaded_extensions, the openssl is not in the array of loaded extensions. What is wrong here? The php_openssl.dll is physically there - I am running a wampserver and it looks ok. But on the execution end it is not working.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depending on how php_openssl.dll was built/linked it depends on libeay32.dll and/or ssleay32.dll. Windows must be able to (also) load those two .dlls into the process running php in order to make the php_openssl.dll available/functional.
Since windows searches for .dlls (amongst other places) in the directory of the executable try placing libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll in the apache/bin directory (where the httpd.exe resides) and restart the webserver.

see also: [Dynamic-Link Library Search Order](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682586%28VS.85%29.aspx)
and [How to use Dependency Walker](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/256872)

Comment: As mysteriously as it started the problem just vanished :\ - thanks anyway

Comment: I know this is a very old post, but I've ran into a similar problem and your suggestion actually fixed it

Comment: I'm running PHP 7 on Apache 2.4, checked php.ini openssl extension, also the apache bin: libeay, ssleay and openssl.exe already there. But still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried restarting your apache server?

And is the DLL in the right place?

Comment: Done that a hundred times but no help I even tried a tweak I found here http://php.net/manual/en/ref.openssl.php#79441 but even that didnt work

Answer (score -2):

This may help you. Copy dll files in windows and windows/system32 folders and then restart Apache server.